# Climate controlled Domed over island, is it feasible?

Tags: science-based

In Warlords Ganymede has been terraformed to a state like the artic circle with it's tropics being like Iceland (this is assuming that Ganymede would have tropics)

The rich and affluent (as well as vacationers) of Ganymede don't want to spend a small fortune just to vacation in the inner planets. The head of ATLAS corporation had a grand idea: dome over smaller islands and terraform their interiors into a (Earth) tropics enviroment.

Now knowing a little bit on how islands work I think you could have the dome anchored into the underwater bits (I don't know a fancy name for it). But I don't know what else would be needed to keep the dome from collapsing. For if anchoring the dome their is a bad idea.

Notes:

The regulation equipment is hidden under ground to keep the scenic views intact. Some would be located on the surface or if possible built into the roof of the dome (or all three)

Think of this dome as a almost complete sphere (has to grab the undersea parts of the island)

Comment: Sure it's feasible.  All you need is a sufficient amount of energy and resources.

Comment: kinda already exists. https://www.amusingplanet.com/2012/11/tropical-island-resortworld-largest.html

Comment: This sounds like The Truman Show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's reasonably possible. Doing a full structural calculation would take some time, but an icosahedron dome can be a very efficient structure.

The hard limit for height would be about 1/3 of the material's free breaking length, which would be reduced by structure and by external loads. Now, Ganymede has a gravity of just 0.15g, making collapse even easier to resist. There will be loads on the dome, but presumably Ganymede won't have much of a weather system.

The dome will be visible. Meteorite impacts regularly punching holes in it are a concern.

The hard part here is terraforming Ganymede, which doesn't get enough solar radiation to sustain an Earth-like temperature, and doesn't have enough gravity to retain a dense atmosphere. Compared to solving these problems, a tropical dome is child's play.

Actually, realistically, you'd need domes to maintain an Iceland-like environment on Ganymede in the first place.

Comment: I tried to ask how to terraform Ganymede and it got down voted into the abyss

Comment: Simply put, Ganymede has too little gravity to retain an Earth-like atmosphere. That makes it non-terraformable in the conventional sense - a planet open to space with breathable air over the surface. Barring very advanced (likely interstellar level) tech, Ganymede would have to rely on domes for creating semi-open breathable environments.